# Scrapy request callback doesn't enter next function

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

Here is my code:

```
import scrapy

class BookingSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'booking-spider'
    allowed_domains = ['booking.com']
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.booking.com/country.de.html?aid=356980;label=gog235jc-1DCAIoLDgcSAdYA2gsiAEBmAEHuAEHyAEP2AED6AEB'
        '-AECiAIBqAIDuAK7q7DyBcACAQ;sid=8de61678ac61d10a89c13a3941fd3dcd'
    ]

    # get country page
    def parse(self, response):

        for countryurl in response.xpath('//a[contains(text(),"Schweiz")]/@href'):
            url = response.urljoin(countryurl.extract())
            print("COUNTRYURL", url)
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_country)

    # get page of all hotels in a country
    def parse_country(self, response):

        for hotelsurl in response.xpath('//a[@class="bui-button bui-button--secondary"]/@href'):
            url = response.urljoin(hotelsurl.extract())
            print("HOTELURL", url)
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_hotel)

    def parse_hotel(self, response):

        print("entering parse_hotel")
        hotelurl = response.xpath('//*[(@ id = "hp_hotel_name")]')
        print("URL", hotelurl)
```

It doesn't go in the `parse_hotel` function. I can't understand why? 
Where is my mistake? Thank you in advance for your suggestions!

Comment: Can you explain what output you want from the program

Comment: The program should go on the hotel page where I want to scrape data. I want to see the output of xpath in the ```parse_hotel``` function but it sticks in the previous function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is on this line

```
response.xpath('//a[@class="bui-button bui-button--secondary"]/@href')
```

Here your XPATH extracts such urls:

```
https://www.booking.com/searchresults.de.html?dest_id=204;dest_type=country&
```

But they should be something like this:

```
https://www.booking.com/searchresults.de.html?label=gen173nr-1DCAIoLDgcSAdYBGhSiAEBmAEHuAEHyAEM2AED6AEB-AECiAIBqAIDuAKz_uDyBcACAQ;sid=a3807e20e99c61282850cfdf02041c07;dest_id=204;dest_type=country&
```

Because of this, your spider tries to open same webpage and it gets blocked by Scrapy Dupefilter. That is reason why callback is not called.

I think, missing part in url is generated by JavaScript.

Comment: Its true! The same in the first function! Thank you for your help!